# Any chance to play h264 stream from ip cam?

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, h.264, flex4.5

I'm working on a h264 flash player. I'm getting a bytestream (from ip cam) of raw h264 through http connection and i have to play it. 
As far as i know, flash cannot play any stream directly, i have to wrap it in flv container. So, what i have to do is to get a bytearray, search 00 00 00 01 (the NAL start prefix code) and add FLV tags to this frame and then with NetStream.appendBytes() add this finally to stage.
The question is - is that the right way? I mean, can i transform a raw h264 to flv stream if i just add a FLV tags to those frames? May be there is a more simple way to play raw h264 from ip cam?

Comment: Check this out. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3717176/as3-video-encoding-at-runtime-with-high-compression-h-264

Answer (score 1):

Hello…I really hope this helps…I have worked with various forms of online video for various entities; from that I do know that Adobe has about 12 years in when it comes to PlayBack…So if you are stuck using it --- YouTube still uses it..?

I put together an AS3 example that retrieves the value of the objectEncoding property along with a header for the contents of your frame [the order file]-- In order to generate what you need with Binary you will utilize calls at appendBytes ()--  this adds bytes into the FIFO until an FLV tag is complete…once a FLV tag is complete it moves to the buffer [Thread: playout] using  A call to appendBytes():  this buffer will inform you as to when to use FLV tags. The Remaining bytes that don’t form a complete FLV tag go into the FIFO Bytes (moved @ playout buffer) in the FIFO.

Here is option 2: NetStream object has two buffers: the FIFO from appendBytes () to the NetStream () Object, and the [playout] buffer. The FIFO is the partial-FLV-tag reassembled; it contains no more than one incomplete FLV tag:
Calling NetStream .seek. Flush || buffers. Seek gives native access to:
appendBytesAction -> readObject -> object… Here your data is in serialized AMF 
from the ByteArray and stores it.

The following example reads the order file from the (filename || location for Data) into a ByteArray (in Bytes), uncompressed it, and calls readObject () to store it in an each () loop construct to add each node to the display:

```
package 
{
import flash.display.*; 
import flash.events.*; 
import flash.net.*; 
import flash.filesystem.*; 
import flash.utils.ByteArray;
import flash.utils.*;

function wBytes(file:String, data:ByteArray):void{  
     var oFile:File = File.desktopDirectory;
     oFile = oFile.resolvePath(file);
     var oStream:FileStream = new FileStream();
     oStream.open(oFile, FileMode.WRITE);
     oStream.writeBytes(data, 0, data.length); 
     oStream.close(); 
     var iFile = iFile.resolvePath(file);
     var iStream:FileStream = new FileStream();
     iStream.open(iFile, FileMode.READ);
     iStream.readBytes(data);
     iStream.close();
 }
 function readBinBytes():void {
     var iBytes:ByteArray = new ByteArray();
     readFileIntoByteArray("order", iBytes);
     iBytes.position = 0; 
     iBytes.uncompress(CompressionAlgorithm.DEFLATE);
     iBytes.position = 0
     var uVariables:UVariablesiables = new UVariablesiables( "one=1&two=2" )
     uVariables.decode("amp=" + encodeURIComponent( "&" ) );
     uVariables.tree = 3; 
     uVariables.amp2 = "&&";
     var urlRequest:URLRequest = new URLRequest()
     urlRequest.data = uVariables;

     readFileIntoByteArray("order", iBytes);
     iBytes.position = 0;
     iBytes.uncompress(CompressionAlgorithm.DEFLATE); 
     iBytes.position = 0;    
}
function readFileIntoByteArray(Name:String, data:ByteArray):void{
     var fIN:File = File.desktopDirectory
     fIN = fIN.resolvePath(Name)
     var FS:FileStream = new FileStream();
     FS.open(fIN, FileMode.READ);
     FS.readBytes(data);
     FS.close()
     var rq:URLRequest = new URLRequest(FS)
     var variables:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
     variables.dataFormat = URLLoaderDataFormat.VARIABLE
     variables.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, function push(event:Event) 
                                               { variables = URLLoader(event.target) }
     try{variables.load(rq} 
         catch(error:*){} 
}
```

}

These 3 Methods should provide both the speed and logic for Most PlayBack environments using RAW H.26+: Frame Rate is not specified – easy as it sounds ~ that’s another layer of work that Most companies pay for…hope it helps. It’s not a fix-all but you are working on something that can take weeks. Good Luck.